# Replace a String in the File Name in Unix

Tags: shell

I have 3 files in one directory like below:

```
file_str_23.txt  
file_jan_24.txt  
file_feb_25.txt
```

Here I would like to replace the first file name 'file_str' with 'file_', so finally the file name should be 'file_23.txt'.

The problem is that I don't know the exact number in the file name, so I should go with 'file_str' string only.

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change single file's name, use `mv`:

```
mv file_str_23.txt file_23.txt
```

And if you want to do this in batch, you could try `rename`, which accepts regular expression:

```
rename 's/_.*?_/_/' file_*
```

---

First argument is a Perl regex substitution expression. It's general form is:

```
s/WHAT_TO_LOOK_FOR/WHAT_TO_PUT_INSTEAD/
```

In our case WHAT_TO_LOOK_FOR is `_.*?_` and WHAT_TO_PUT_INSTEAD is `_`.

Now, `_.*?_` means: "Match underscore followed by any number of any characters (`.*?`), followed by another underscore". For instance, in string "file_str_23.txt" it will match "str".

This matched part of the file name will be replaced with `_` (our WHAT_TO_PUT_INSTEAD part).

Comment: Hmmm Here the problem is I dont know the exact number in the file name, so i should go with 'file_str' string only.

Comment: Okay, see updated answer. Your orignal question didn't mention batch rename ;p

Comment: Can you please explain 's/_.*?_/_/' part?

Answer (score 1):

if you're using bash, you could also use this

```
for F in file_*.txt ; do 
    mv ${F} file_${F#file_*_}
done
```

Which is super easy to make into a one-liner:

```
for F in file_*.txt ; do mv ${F} file_${F#file_*_} ; done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for loop that should work without any external utility:

```
for f in *_*_*.txt; do
    mv "$f" "${f/_*_/_}"
done
```